# Is there a way to enforce a generic type to hold only a specific variant of the enum?

Tags: enums, rust, generic-programming, type-safety

With this definition of `Strct`, it is possible for `values` to hold any variant of the `Test` enum:

```
enum Test {
    A,
    B,
    C,
}

struct Strct {
    values: Vec<Test>,
}
```

Is there a way to enforce it to hold only a specific variant of the enum? E.g. `Vec<A>` or `Vec<B>` or `Vec<C>` for that specific case.

Comment: TL;DR the duplicates: no.

Comment: @Shepmaster I know you are aware of this RFC, as you commented on it 2 years ago. Kind of relevant: https://github.com/varkor/rfcs/blob/enum-variant-types/text/0000-enum-variant-types.md